# insert custom html entities between content using php foreach

Tags: php, html

I'm using simple dom parrser 
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

says I've table like this

```
<table class="tb">...</table>
<table class="tb">...</table>
<table class="tb">...</table>
<table class="tb">...</table>
<table class="tb">...</table>
```

I do

```
$ads = "<div>ads banner here</div>";

foreach($html->find('div[class="tb"]') as $element){
       echo $element->src . '<br>';
       $element->outertext .= $ads;
}
```

then the ads banner will loop through all the table and I'll get 5 ads block.. how limit the numbers? like I want only one ad block to appear btw the first and second table.

Comment: what would be the point of doing a find for `div.tb`, when your html snippet has `table.tb`? And if you want only 5, then keep a counter and `break` out of the loop once you've dealt with 5.

Comment: What Marc said - add a counter parameter that you can use to track itterations inside the forEach.  That way you aren't limited to the scope of the loop itself.

Comment: Do you mean you want to spread what you have in the array between the tables or do you mean use the first banner and ignore the rest?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($html->find('div[class="tb"]') as $i => $element){
```

Assuming the array uses indexed keys `$i` is your iteration index, **starting at zero**, so to limit the number break the loop when you've had enough

```
foreach($html->find('div[class="tb"]') as $i => $element){
    if ($i > 0) break; // show only the first
    // if ($i > 4) break; // show the first 5
    echo $element->src . '<br>';
    $element->outertext .= $ads;
}
```

If you are using an associative array, you would count instead.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($html->find('div[class="tb"]') as $element){
    $i++;
    if ($i > 1) break; // show only the first
    // if ($i > 5) break; // show the first five
    echo $element->src . '<br>';
    $element->outertext .= $ads;
}
```